# In QtWebkit, how to install the callback from C++ to Javaobject window?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qtwebkit

I have implemented the HTML-JS, this calls the C++ method from the JS using `QtWebkit`. I am able to do it successfully. Now, I want to send a callback to JavaScript window from the C++ method. How can I do so?

Here is my code.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWebFrame>
#include <QWebPage>
#include <QWebView>

class MyJavaScriptOperations : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE qint32 MultOfNumbers(int a, int b) {
        qDebug() << a * b;
        return (a*b);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWebView *view = new QWebView();
    view->resize(400, 500);
    view->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("myoperations", new MyJavaScriptOperations);
    view->load(QUrl("./shreyas.html"));
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

The Java script is here.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>


function Multiply()
{
   var result = myoperations.MultOfNumbers(document.forms["DEMO_FORM"]["Multiplicant_A"].value, document.forms["DEMO_FORM"]["Multiplicant_B"].value);
   document.getElementById("answer").value = result;

}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="DEMO_FORM">
Multiplicant A: <input type="number" name="Multiplicant_A"><br>
Multiplicant B: <input type="number" name="Multiplicant_B"><br>
Result : <input type="number" id="answer" name="Multiplicant_C"><br>
<input type="button" value="Multiplication_compute_on_C++" onclick="Multiply()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shreyas, why is it tagged with qtdbus? Also, please note that Qt and QT are different projects.

Comment: what is the difference between qt and QT?

Comment: Check the [tagwiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/qt/info).

Comment: Ok, got it. Now, I am waiting for the answer. If I can make a callback, then the UI part  is complete. This will give more value to webkit then in the context of JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can somehow call a JS callback directly, but in a pinch you could use your main frame's [evaluateJavascript()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qwebframe.html#evaluateJavaScript) method to call some JS from C++.

Or you can connect to signals from the JavaScript side, see [Qt QWEBview JavaScript callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975658/qt-qwebview-javascript-callback) for some ideas.

A good overview over the connection mechanisms can also be found in the [Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qtwebkit-bridge.html)

Comment: Would you mind answering my question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060192/why-callback-to-js-is-not-working-in-the-qtweb-using-signals-in-the-following-co